# building 32 exe on 64 bit open suse linux gives link error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

In my VM, I have installed open suse linux 64 bit.
Trying to build an exe for 32 bit.

But on running the command :
**g++ prg1.cpp -o prg1 -m32**

I get the following error:

> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   skipping incompatible
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/libstdc++.so when searching for
>   -lstdc++ /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/libstdc++.a
>   when searching for -lstdc++
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lstdc++ collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

To build for 32 i have installed the necessary rpms for 32 bit.

On running 
**g++ -print-search-dirs** , the output is

> install: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/ programs:
>   =/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/
>   libraries:
>   =/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/:/lib/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib/:/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

Although the 32 bit libstdc++ is also installed, the linker is not able to link to it. Is any specific flag required to tell the linker to build 32 bit
Or I have to install any other package?

Comment: `cannot find -lstdc++` is saying it cannot find the 32-bit c++ libs. Double-check you have all necessary libs installed.

Comment: For example, on 13.1 you need: `gcc-32bit-4.8-2.1.2.x86_64` `gcc48-32bit-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1.x86_64` and `libgcc_s1-32bit-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1.x86_64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To build for 32 i have installed the necessary rpms for 32 bit.

No, you have not.

Note that in order to build programs you need 32-bit runtime *and* development libraries. I am guessing that you've installed the former, but not the latter.

Comment: I had missed installing - libstdc++48-devel-32bit-4.8.1_20130909-3.2.1.x86_64.rpm. It is building now. Thanks.